# Euler's Phi function congruence Proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation, totient-function

I have the following problem, and I'm a little stuck on how I go from the given hypothesis to the conclusion. I'm not too sure how I can alter the term in the (mod) without altering everything else.

***Prove that if*** $$a^{\phi(b)} + b^{\phi(a)}\equiv1\pmod{ab}$$
***then***

$$a^{\phi(b)} + b^{\phi(a)}\equiv 1+ab\pmod{2ab}$$

I ended up using the definition of mods where

$$ab\ |\ (a^{\phi(b)} + b^{\phi(a)}) - 1$$

but I couldn't figure out how to use this to get to the conclusion and I also don't understand how I can alter the stuff inside the mod without altering everything else.
Thank you in advance for helping me out with this!

Comment: I have a feeling you’ve omitted some precondition such as $a$,$b$ are both odd.  The first line is easy enough to prove for $(a,b)=1$ so it seems like an odd thing to take as an assumption unless the second line follows by an even easier argument (which would be the case if $ab$ is odd).

Answer (score 1):

This statement is false.  Take $a=2$ and $b=5$.  Then $\phi(a) = 1$ and $\phi(b)=4$.  We have $2^4 + 5^1 = 21 \equiv 1 \pmod{10}$, but $21 \not\equiv 1 + 10 \pmod{20}$.